# Create a workflow email with a link that opens InfoPath form filler

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, infopath

My Environment is: Windows 7 & 10 - SharePoint 2013 - InfoPath 2013 - Office 2013 & 2016.

I have a custom form library in SharePoint 2013 with many (54) promoted fields from InfoPath 2013. I have created a workflow that uses **[%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]** to create a link to the item. The issue is that the link tried to open in the browser. The link is formed:

> http://*myintranet.com*/dev/ATRs1/31.xml

which is identical to the link in the SharePoint library, Name (linked to document with edit menu) which work fine and open the InfoPath form filler.

```
The error I receive is: Error - This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath.
```

I have read several articles on this, however most are for an older 2010 environment.

My question is,

> How to I get that .xml to open in the InfoPath filler program from a
>   link in an email or a different way to form the URL to cause it to
>   open the InfoPath form filler?